# Non-full-screen windows in matchbox-wm

Tags: window-management, matchbox

Does anybody of you know if there's a possibility to "un-full-screen" windows in `matchbox-wm`?
I tried already building it using all possible "compile-time enables", but nothing worked out.

Additionally the documentation page at http://projects.o-hand.com/matchbox is unreachable...
Does anybody know an alternative link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matchbox support modal windows, but it doesn't support to un-maximize top level windows by design, simply because it goes against it's main purposse.

https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/allum/allum_html/matchbox.html

> **Dialogs**
>
> Matchbox attempts to accommodate application dialog windows. Rather than being resized to fill the display like their parent application windows, their requested size is usually honored, (if within the display), and they are not statically positioned, allowing the user to drag them about the display.

Comment: Please add a reference if you can.

Comment: Reference added.